# PHP - memory exhausted error randomly trigerred on production server

Tags: php, memory

I am randomly (around 20 times a day) getting this error on a production server (PHP 7.0.32):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4787537204 bytes)
```

The "presence" of the error is quite low, so far, but because I am not sure what is wrong, I am woried about the future and bigger problems.

I run this code at the top of the page when the error happens:

```
    $curTime = time();
    $dataIds = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10");

    $end = array();
    $update = array();
    $dbUpdate = array();

    foreach($dataIds as $id) {
        $f = fopen( "./data/{$id}.json", "r");
        if ($f === false) {
            continue;
        }

        $data = fread($f, 1024);
        fclose($f);
        $data = json_decode($data, true);

        if (!isset($data['input'])) {
            continue;
        }

        $endDate = $data['input'][0]['end'];
        $updateDate = $data['input'][0]['start'];
        $dbUpdateDate = $data['input'][0]['update'];

        $end[$id] = ($endDate !== "") ? strtotime($endDate." UTC") : $curTime;
        $update[$id] = ($updateDate !== "") ? strtotime($updateDate." UTC") : $curTime;
        $dbUpdate[$id] = ($dbUpdateDate !== "") ? strtotime($dbUpdateDate." UTC") : $curTime;
    }
```

And error is trigerred on this line:

```
 $end[$id] = ($endDate !== "") ? strtotime($endDate." UTC") : $curTime;
```

I am unable to reproduce the problem with the development server and I am not sure what can cause this and how to debug this (I cannot enable debug features on production server). There is no other warning or notice prior to the fatal error.

The json data files are small, around 500 bytes. They are, however, updated from a cron job. So I can, in theory, open incomplete file. But in this case, `json_decode` returns `null` as I have tested.

The json sample:

```
{
    "input":    [{
            "id":   "1",
            "start":    "2019-11-15 06:00:00",
            "end":  "2019-11-18 12:00:00",
            "update":   "2019-11-15 10:52:44"
        }]
}
```

Comment: This question boils down to: Why the heck is PHP trying to allocate 4.4 Gigabytes of RAM for something that seems to be relatively simple.

Comment: Are you sure your server has not been virus and is not including a file though some means that's doing more?

Comment: @MartinBarker AFAIK, that wont cause `strtotime` to request for 4GB. And to affect PHP itself, the virus have to be in sudo mode, which is unlikely. Plus there are no other issues like this.

Comment: @MartinPerry Really a privilege escalation is unlikely I think not, also any user with root access and an SSH terminal is an entry point for a virus. oh look there is putty saved config that tells me where the private key is, and the server address it's connecting to... or using a none official repo for PHP installation there are loads of way for a virus to get into php, there is also forced includes that could be exploited

Comment: @MartinBarker I have PHP from official repo and SSH is locked to IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poking around a bit (see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59883899/2097290) that started off on a totally different tangent), it seems that the huge memory allocation of over 4 GB of RAM happens inside of `strtotime`. It is unclear if this is related to PHP bug #53502 (is an old PHP 5.3 bug, currently marked as closed) or not.

However, changing

```
$end[$id] = ($endDate !== "") ? strtotime($endDate." UTC") : $curTime;
```

to

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$end[$id] = ($endDate !== "") ? strtotime($endDate) : $curTime;
```

gets rid of the phenomenon and runs smoothly. It is currently unclear if any specific value of `$endDate` is causing this or what else could be a contributing factor.

Answer (score 2):

This is the only reasonable explanation I could come up with, please check if my deductions are true.

Your `$dataIds` are not small integers, but in the billions in your actual code. Fore some reason, PHP seems to have `$this->end` typed as a string not as an Array. Effectively, you're doing this:

```
$stuff='string';
$stuff[5000000000]='y'; // will allocate 5 GB of RAM, exceeding your 128M maximum
```

when you *think* your're doing this:

```
$stuff=new Array();
$stuff[5000000000]='y'; // will allocate just a few Bytes since it is an asssociative Array
```

You will have to dig around your other parts of code to see why this might be the case

Comment: I am telling PHP to use "arrays" with `$end = array();` (I have updated the question). The keys are strings, they should not be treated as numbers.

Comment: @MartinPerry *should not* may be the correct term here. I fail to see how anything else on that line might request 4GB of RAM other than the assignment.

Comment: I also suspect whether there may exist some ill-formated date sting that can trigger strtotime (in PHP 7.0.32) to request such amount of memory or lead to some memory leak. However, I dont know how to output the date string together with fatal error.

Comment: `= array()` is a binary array, `new Array();` is effectively a `HashMap` it's a management object around Heap Data

Comment: @MartinPerry I find it unlikely (but possible) for *strtotime* to have a 4GB Memory leak. But just in case, you could separate your calculation from your assignment by putting it into a temporary variable first and see where it crashes. (e.g. $tmp=($endDate !== "") ? strtotime($endDate." UTC") : $curTime; $end[$id]=$tmp )

Comment: @Hazzit I have separated calculation and assignment and error is still at line with `strtotime`.

Comment: @MartinPerry How unusual. Next step in my eyes is swapping the ternary expression to an if-then construct on separate lines: if ($endDate !="") { $tmp=strtotime($endDate." UTC"); } else { $tmp=$curTime } $end[$id]=$tmp. Also, there used to be a Memory leak with time zones, but that was years ago (PHP 5.3, bug #53502). Possibly still worth trying: use date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); instead of appending the " UTC" string.

Comment: @Hazzit I have the remove ternary expression and also did the timezone setting directly and not via appending " UTC". Now the error seems to be gone. However, I did this only for `end`, the other two parts (`updated`, `dbUpdate`) remain unchanged, which is even more strange, because they should trigger the same error.

Comment: @MartinPerry The `date_default_timezone_set()` function will effect all three subsequent assignments. so may be you can now roll back your changes one at a time to see when the error comes back. Also, you might want to add some logging to be able to see if there's anything special about the data when it crashes.

Comment: @Hazzit It seems that the problem is gone. Can you post the solution with timezones as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add this below to your script (put it on very top)

```
 ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

you can later set `-1` to something like `256` if you had `64` or something less which wasn't sufficient.

Comment: This is not a real solution, more like a hotfix. This does not solve where the problem is and why it is there.

Comment: Subsequently to the comment above and the error that is happening all this will serve to do is crash the Server as it will run out of memory.